# Как сделать проверку на ввод символов

Tags: linux, c

```
scanf("%d", &casenum);

while ( casenum != 1 ){

        printf("Ошибка! Введено символ. Введите еще раз.\n");

        scanf("%d", &casenum);

    }
```

Если введено символ функция printf зацикливается при том что scanf не считывает значение с клавиатуры. Для компилации кода использую терминал в Linux Ubuntu.
Как сделать чтобы при ошибке можно было нормально ввести значение и продолжить работу программы?

Полный пример функции.

```
int menu(void) {
    int casenum=0, counter = 0;
    char answerYes[] = "y", ans[10];
        do {
            printf("+----------------------------------+\n");
            printf("|0|Вихід                           |\n");
            printf("|1|Ввести дані                     |\n");
            printf("|2|Видалити запис                  |\n");
            printf("|3|Видалити всі дані про місяць    |\n");
            printf("|4|Відсортувати за спадінням       |\n");
            printf("|5|Найменші витрати на харчування  |\n");
            printf("|6|Найбільші витрати на квартпліту |\n");
            printf("|7|Витрати більші ніж зарплата     |\n");
            printf("+----------------------------------+\n");

            scanf("%d", &casenum);

            while( casenum < 0 && casenum > 7 ){

                printf("Помилка! Ви ввели символ. Введіть ще раз.\n");

                int c;
                while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

                scanf("%d", &casenum);
            }

            switch (casenum)
            {
                case 0: return 0; break;
                case 1: add(); counter = 1; break;
                case 2: deleteAllDataMonth(); counter = 2; break;
                case 3: sorting(); counter = 3; break;
                case 4: minFootCosts(); counter = 4; break;
                case 5: maxCostsForRent(); counter = 5; break;
                case 6: spendingMoreThanSalary(); counter = 6; break;
                default: system("cls || clear"); printf("Ви ввели неістуючу команду!\n");
                break;
            }
        } while (counter == 0);
        printf("\n\nБажаєте повернутися в меню або вийти з програми? (y/n)\n");
        scanf("%s", ans);
        if (strcmp(ans, answerYes)==0) {

            system("cls || clear");
            menu();
        }
        else return 0;

        return 0;
}
```

Здесь я исправил код, но проблема осталась. По идеи при вводе символа она должна выводить ошибку, но програма просто закрываеться.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что если scanf не смогла распознать число ( в Вашем случае), то она не прочитает ни символа с входной строки. И это будет повторятся много-много раз.

Как решить данную проблему? есть три подхода.

1) Если не удалось прочитать, вычитать все до конца и попробовать снова.

scanf("%d", &casenum);

```
while ( casenum != 1 ){

    printf("Ошибка! Введено символ. Введите еще раз.\n");

    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

    scanf("%d", &casenum);

}
```

2) второй способ - читать сразу всю строку (с помощью fgets), и потом ее парсить sscanf ( [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1716013/why-is-scanf-causing-infinite-loop-in-this-code)).

3) третий - читать хитро. вот таким `scanf("%d%s", &casenum, buf)`. В buf будет читаться хвост строки. В большинстве случаев его можно игнорировать, а можно и проанализировать.

Comment: Должна быть проверка являеться ли введеное значение цыфрой либо символом, если введеное значение цыфра, то програма продолжает роботу дальше, если символом, то програма дает возможность ввести цыфру до тех пор пока пользователь ее не введет.

Comment: Дело в том что потом в коде у меня идет оператор выбора:switch (casenum)
   {
    case 0: return 0; break;
    case 1: add(); counter = 1; break;
    case 2: deleteAllDataMonth(); counter = 2; break;
    case 3: sorting(); counter = 3; break;
    case 4: minFootCosts(); counter = 4; break;
    case 5: maxCostsForRent(); counter = 5; break;
    case 6: spendingMoreThanSalary(); counter = 6; break;
    default: system("cls || clear"); printf("Ви ввели неістуючу команду!\n");
    break;
   }

Answer (score -2):

Платформонезависивомого решения для языков С и С++ вы не найдете эти языки переполнение типа не считают ошибкой и исключительных ситуаций для этого не предусмотрено. Выход только один это писать свой платформозависимый обработчик на ассемблере, в процессоре для этого есть флаг переполнения в регистре флагов вот его то и можно использовать.

используйте функции  read() getc() fgets() проверяйте введенный массив, а потом преобразуйте int в char используй stroul()

Comment: В вопросе нет ни слова о переполнении типа, вообще-то... И еще - **платформонезависимый ... на ассемблере** - это пять! :)